# How to change wallpaper in Windows 11 setup?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-11

I had mounted the install.wim using DISM and made a SetupComplete.cmd which injected a custom Root Certificate and Changed the default wallpaper to what I specified. The contents of the Setup\Script folder are as follows:

1. **SetupComplete.cmd** (which contains the following code)

   ```
   powershell -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned && powershell -File "%SystemRoot%\Setup\Scripts\chgwallpaper.ps1"
   ```
2. **chgwallpaper.ps1** (which contains the code to change wallpaper)

   ```
   #Modify Path to the picture accordingly to reflect your infrastructure
   $imgPath="%SystemRoot%\Setup\Scripts\MyPicture.jpg"
   $code = @' 
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
   namespace Win32{ 

     public class Wallpaper{ 
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)] 
         static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction , int uParam , string lpvParam , int fuWinIni) ; 

         public static void SetWallpaper(string thePath){ 
            SystemParametersInfo(20,0,thePath,3); 
         }
    }
   } 

   add-type $code 

   #Apply the Change on the system 
   [Win32.Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper($imgPath)
   ```
3. MyPicture.jpg (the image file)

Now, the problem is that other components of setupcomplete.cmd (which is not mentioned here, like installing a custom root certificate) works perfectly. Even this scripts executes perfectly but on the first login, I see the image is not changes. When I run this .cmd file again, changing nothing in it, but manually after the install, it runs perfectly. It is confusing that the certificate part is executed properly, but wallpaper part did not. I'm beginning to think that Windows is actually overriding the change in wallpaper during the first logon. Please help.

Comment: The `SetWallpaper` does it for the current user (which you don't have at this stage), not for all future users.

Comment: Try : In registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes` to add a REG_EXPAND_SZ item named `DesktopBackground` and set it to the path of your image (where it's accessible to all users). This is an old registry key, but it might still work.